# Why do peoples(Europe, Asia, Africa, etc) call "God" in very similar ways?

Tags: phonetics, etymology, cross-linguistic

UK: dieu(the motto on passport - French)/deity(English word)
China: tien(Chinese Wade-Giles... t->d)
South Africa: modimo(o->əʊ)
New Zealand: atua(Maori... t->d)
North America: tirawa(Pawnee... w->u t->d)
South America: tatitu(Aymara... t->d)
etc

Comment: How do those words similar? Esp. with modimo I don't find any thing in common with the others

Comment: No apparent scientific question

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc "with modimo I don't find any thing in common"... modimo=məʊdiməʊ and dieu - you see, it's almost the same!

Comment: I don't see how they are same

Comment: @user6726 "No apparent scientific question"... of course, science says it's impossible(separate language families). The only problem: they are indeed very similar.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc "I don't see how they are same"... modimo=məʊdiməʊ and dieu... Both share "di". Both end with "eu". Almost the same.

Comment: As for me, I can find similarity between any two words from any two languages.

Comment: @YellowSky "I can find similarity between any two words"... **Please tell us about similarity between "Yellow" and "Sky".**

Comment: Easily! And not only one similarity, there're lots of similarities between these two words: 1. Both of them are English words. 2. Both of them start with a capital letter. 3. The 1st one begins with Y, the other one ends with it. 4. The 1st one has 6 letters, the 2nd one has 3, and 6=2×3. 5. Both of them have diphthongs. 6.  And last but not the least, both of the words do exist. Is it enough?

Comment: @YellowSky **Hey! We are talking about phonetics.**

Comment: The Aymara word you provide derives from the word "Father" and arose in use amongst missionaries and converts. Deities and supernatural entities are called by their names.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, given that there are 7,000 or so known languages, then it is always possible to select some approximate meaning like "god; cow; eat; big" and pick words from those 7,000 languages that are sufficiently similar in meaning and form that you could assume some deeper significance to that coincidence. As a starter, to establish significance, you would need to show that these forms that you offer are actually the words for "god" in those languages. As a case in point, there is no language "South African". That word (Setswana) means "Man-eater", which is an expression used to refer to "God", and derives from the verb 'eat' which is /li/. If your criteria for "similarity" are loose enough, you can always find a "similarity" in a half-dozen languages. I would not be surprised if readers here could identify a half-dozen tangential similarities in the form of the word for "cow" across human languages.

Comment: "there are 7,000 or so known languages, then it is always possible to select"... **Major examples: dieu(motto of British Monarch), tien(Imperial Seal of China), Elohim(Israel's Genesis 1:1 - o=əʊ, Spanish "Dios" = Yaqui "Lios") - these are major examples, and these are still similar.** "need to show that these forms that you offer are actually the words for god"... **dieu is in motto of British Monarch, tien is in Imperial Seal of China, modimo is in "Modimo Re Boka Wena"(Mighty God we thank you), tirawa is the creator god of the Pawnee people, etc.**